# ng-package: embedd dynamic version string into Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-packagr

Is it possible to modify the ng-packagr workflow in order to embed the compile-time generated version information such as a version core, pre-release version or build information into the bundle and make it available to library consumers such as via a `VersionService` that the library could provide.

Answer (score 0):

Our application imports an `environment.json` file generated at build time with a `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` plugin, the latter extracting the information (among others) from the `package.json` file.

TypeScript can just import a .json file as a regular JS object, and such file can be generated with the information you want.

Comment: I use the custom-webpack plugin with angular applications, but libraries use ng-package and the this approach fails.